Getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid descriptor for io/jsonwebtoken while building Maven project in Java 21
This is the exact error im getting:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid descriptor: [io/jsonwebtoken/JwtBuilder0org/springframework/security/core/AuthenticationgetNameclaimio/jsonwebtoken/securit

Here's my pom.xml file:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-impl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.6</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20240303</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.razorpay/razorpay-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.razorpay</groupId>
        <artifactId>razorpay-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
       </dependencies>

I tried to build the Maven project and was expecting it to be built successfully.

Why using org.json instead of the default of SB (jackson; also used by jjwt)? Also why defining manually the versions of spring-boot-starter-mail... and why do you need jjwt-api... oAuth2/OpenIDConnect is supported via spring-security (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/index.html)? And which version of SB do you use?

I'm using SpringBoot 3.3.4

why are you using jjwt? spring security has full support for all authentication standards that should be using jwts.
